# Correlation dependent on samples

Tags: matlab, statistics, correlation, random

I have a variable y that depends on some variables x1 ∈ [x1_min,x1_max], x2 ∈ [x2_min,x2_max], x3 ∈ [x3_min,x3_max] and y can be a matrix as well, i.e. y=y(x1,x2,x3). I want to detect which among x1,x2,x3 is less relevant to determine the value of y.

I am using the following code in Matlab:

```
x = rand(1000,3);  % x1, x2, x3 are the columns of x
y = fct(x);    % A generic function of x1, x2, x3
[corr_mat, p_val] = corrcoef(x,y);
[i,j] = find(p_val > 0.5);
disp([i,j])
```

The problem is that the resulting indices strongly depend on the random samples (even if I increase the number of samples). How can I get a more precise measure?

As a simple alternative example, y=x1+x2+x3, with x1∈[50,80], x2∈[0,1], x3∈[0,1]. Clearly, the value of y depends much more on x1 than the other 2 variables. How do I quantify this dependence?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Here is what I mean with "quantification" or "relevance". I want to detect which variable determines very small changes in y, i.e. in the previous example x2 and x3 makes y to vary less than x1 does.

Comment: This is just a thought but would the standard deviation help? `x1` has a larger standard deviation than the other two.

Comment: @kkuila I don't think that the standard deviation would help. As an example, imagine to have x1∈[1000,1030], x2∈[0,30], x3∈[0,30], in this case they have the same standard deviation, but x1 is much more relevant.

Comment: and if you do `min(x) + std(x)`? Then `x1` would have a higher value than the other two. I am assuming that you say `x1` is more relevant because the minimum value is higher than the other two. Just a thought.

Comment: Then in this case yes, but that would solve only the specific example. I was looking for something that is valid for a generic function of x1,x2,x3, like the correlation matrix is. The only problem is that it is very dependent on the sampling.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what relevance means for you in this specific example? (formulation in mathematical terms would be the best). Based on your comments the following might give you a useful measure of relevance: x = [x1=mean(x1), x2=0, x3=0]; measure = fct(x) + dfct(x)/dx1*std(x1);

Comment: I think what you need is covered in the literature of [sensitivity analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_analysis) and uncertainty analysis. If the arguments (x1,x2,..) are independent than I think the approach I sketched in my previous comment would identify the 'relevant' parameters. It should be repeated for each parameter, and the differentiation could be done numerically - if you have a smooth function -; no sampling is required)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **covariance** and not correlation coefficient. The correlation coefficient is normalized by the variance of each variable to give the same weight to all variables when they have different ranges, and this is exactly what you want to avoid.

```
x1 = 50+30*rand(1000,1); 
x2 = rand(1000,1); 
x3 = rand(1000,1); 

y = x1+x2+x3;

c=cov([x1 x2 x3 y]);
c(1:3,4) % Covariances of x[1-3] and y
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just tried following your suggestion, but the result is still very dependent on the samples in some cases. How can I solve it?

Comment: With the function and ranges from your example, the result should not be very dependant on the sample (you should always find that covariance between x1 and y is much bigger than covariance between x2 and y or between x3 and y). Of course if the function is too complex (not linear) it will not work anymore, but your question has in this case no clear mathematical meaning.